# Hibernate range query - dividing result in group

Tags: hibernate, range

I have 3 records in table. I wanted results in different groups. So i have done range query as,

```
Query q=session.createQuery("select a.firstName,a.lastname from Emp);
q.setFirstResult(startVal);
q.setMaxResults(endVal);
myList = q.list();
System.out.println(myList.size());
```

I have created group as below.These groups generated dynamically.

```
startVal    endval
0           1
2           2
3           3
```

for startVal= 0  , endVal = 1  its working  (returning myList.size() value 1)
for startVal= 2 ,  endVal = 2  its working  (returning myList.size() value 1)

But for startVal= 3 , endVal = 3  ITS NOT WORKING returning myList.size() value 0.

Can anybody help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not start value and end value - it's start value and max results.

So your first range is starting from 0, return me 1 result max (hence your single result).

Your second range is starting from 2, give me 2 results max - in this case there are only 3 results (0, 1, and 2) and since you are starting from 2, there is only one result.

None of these ranges capture the middle row.

Comment: Thanks jeff. So what will be alternative. Or to obtain middle value do I need to do some substractions from obtained start and end values and create range for middle values ?